# Is it possible to call images from outside the public folder or any folder or directory in your computer in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is my code calling from public folder and it works.

```
<img src="/placeImages/{{$image['image_filename']}}"
```

This is my code calling from outside the public folder or from any folder in  the desktop but it's not working. How can I make it work ?

```
<img src="C:\Users\akosijerbey\Desktop/{{$image['image_filename']}}"
```

Comment: what you will do when application goes live ?

Comment: @Abhiskek it will show the pictures sir...:( sorry im still new in laravel... but i already try to save details of image from database and move the image in a designated folder. this is my code "
      $move = $image->move('C:\Users\akosijerbey\Desktop/new', $iname); and its working but when i try to get and view the image in that directory ,no pictures appear..

Comment: @JerbeyCapoquian what is the reasoning behind this? Do you want to restrict access to the photos? etc

Comment: @Muggles honestly i have two projects and i want to make a 1 folder which the two projects can save there images and can also gather the images for viewing but the folder is outside the public folder of the laravel.. moving of image to an specific folder is already ok but when i tried to get the image from that folder, the image is broken ,so it means no image gathered..

Comment: @JerbeyCapoquian what web server are you using?

Comment: @Muggles sir honestly im only using xampp as my workstation..

Answer (score 2):

No.  Only images and files in the public folder will be serve by the webserver.

If you have a folder with files outside of public, a simple trick to have them in public folder is to use [symlinks](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/). (`ln -s` in linux)

Comment: @sir Yada how about if im using windows 8 or 7?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to load the images dynamically using Laravel.

Take a look at the [Response::download](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses) function. Also this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Sentences/3945396) enables you to load the images inline with Laravel 4. Be wary while using these methods though, as serious security flaws can occur if implemented incorrectly.

Since you have mentioned you are using Apache however, I would strongly recommend taking a look at [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/).

Comment: @ muggles sir can you give me a sample code because im still confused how to use response::download ,,

Comment: hi sir..how can i call the filename on the views.blade.php?

Comment: or do you mean to download the image to an specific folder?